# Animate input box in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, template10

[image: Input box]

I want to animate input box just like the one above how to do it in MVVM template 10

I have a list view
and need the search bar just like the image

Comment: what did you tried already? provide as some code

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. We're not magic genie's.... You don't just rub the stack overflow lamp, ask a two sentence question and then get an answer. You need to show some effort on your end. What have you tried? Where is your code? What have you researched? Is there any errors in your output? etc....

Comment: This is all explained, in **great** detail at [Animations overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/animations-overview). Stop being helpless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have attached an solution to your problem. There are two storyboards that are triggered on GotFocus and Lost Focus for an AutoSuggestBox in UWP c#

Here us what I achieved:

[image: Screen Capture]

**XAML :**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="OnCancel">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="70">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderGrid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="51"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderGrid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderGrid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-36.058"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="OnTextBoxFocus">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="70">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderGrid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderGrid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderGrid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-36.058"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="HeaderGrid" Margin="0,0,-1,-0.117" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="51">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" Margin="5,0,1,3" FontSize="36" SelectionHighlightColor="{x:Null}" Foreground="DodgerBlue"/>
        <TextBox Width="1" Height="1" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <Path Data="M0,48 L360,48" Height="1" Margin="0,0,0,0.117" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="DodgerBlue" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid Height="32" Margin="12,8,12,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="searchText" PlaceholderText="Search" QueryIcon="Find" TextMemberPath="name" LostFocus="searchText_LostFocus" GotFocus="searchText_GotFocus"/>
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Cancel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Grid.Column="4" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="70" Click="button_Click"/>
        </Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" Background="#FFECECEC" Margin="0,8,0,0">
            <ListViewItem Content="List View Item 1" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFB9B9B9"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="List View Item 2" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFB9B9B9"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="List View Item 3" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFB9B9B9"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="List View Item 4" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFB9B9B9"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="List View Item 5" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFB9B9B9"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="List View Item 6" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFB9B9B9"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="List View Item 7" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFB9B9B9"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="List View Item 8" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFB9B9B9"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="List View Item 9" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFB9B9B9"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="List View Item 10" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFB9B9B9"/>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

and in code behind **XAML.CS**

```
 private void searchText_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnCancel.Begin();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnCancel.Begin();
    }


    private void searchText_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnTextBoxFocus.Begin();
    }
```

Also dont forget to set width of button = 0 on Initialization.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @SamTholiya glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You can use data binding to bind your title and `Cancel` button's `Visibility` property to property defined in your `ViewModel`, as @Raunaq Patel said, the animations are triggered by `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` event.

So you can for example code like this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="pageHeader" Text="Main Page" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" FontSize="30" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <AutoSuggestBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" GotFocus="{x:Bind ViewModel.Search_GotFocus}"
                            LostFocus="{x:Bind ViewModel.Search_LostFocus}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Width="{Binding BoxWidth}" />

            <TextBlock Text="Cancel" Foreground="BlueViolet" Tapped="{x:Bind ViewModel.Cancel_Tapped}" Width="100"
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"
                       Visibility="{Binding CancelIsVisible}" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="{Binding ListViewEnable}">
            <ListViewItem>Item 1</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Item 2</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Item 3</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Item 4</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Item 5</ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Since you are using Template 10, code behind is for example in the `MainPageViewModel` like this:

```cs
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Visibility _IsVisible;

    public Visibility IsVisible
    {
        get { return _IsVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _IsVisible)
            {
                _IsVisible = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private Visibility _CancelIsVisible;

    public Visibility CancelIsVisible
    {
        get { return _CancelIsVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _CancelIsVisible)
            {
                _CancelIsVisible = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _ListViewEnable;

    public bool ListViewEnable
    {
        get { return _ListViewEnable; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _ListViewEnable)
            {
                _ListViewEnable = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private double _BoxWidth;

    public double BoxWidth
    {
        get { return _BoxWidth; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _BoxWidth)
            {
                _BoxWidth = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        _IsVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        _CancelIsVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
        _ListViewEnable = true;
        _BoxWidth = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
    }

    public void Search_GotFocus(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
        CancelIsVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        ListViewEnable = false;
        BoxWidth = _BoxWidth - 100;
    }

    public void Search_LostFocus(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        CancelIsVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ListViewEnable = true;
        BoxWidth = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
    }

    public void Cancel_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        CancelIsVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ListViewEnable = true;
        BoxWidth = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
    }
}
```

Here you can see the data in `ListView` are fake, you can of course use `DataTemplate` and bind collection to the `ItemSource` of the `ListView`. Here is the rendering image of my sample:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

It's AutoSuggestBox.

You can see how to use in https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlAutoSuggestBox

And you can see summary on https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/auto-suggest-box?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I think the msdn example is tell you how to do it.And I'm sorry about my last line because it's chinese.And the English line is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280217.aspx